# Font-Names="Verdana" в одном окошке работает корректно, а в другом нет

Tags: asp.net, кодировка, .net, шрифты

Добрый день! Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, что не так написала, что у клиента  фонт Verdana во одном окошке текст показывает корректно, а в другом нет?

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" Font-Names="Verdana" GroupingText="Тип" > 
Panel лежит в asp:Table там тоже задан Font-Names="Verdana"

В первом окошке такой же код и работает корректно.

Answer (score 1):

А может, лучше через файл CSS назначать стили и шрифты, 
примерно так:

```
 @font-face { font-family: 'FuturaNewBook'; src: url('/fonts/futura_new_book_reg-webfont.eot'); src: url('/fonts/futura_new_book_reg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/futura_new_book_reg-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/futura_new_book_reg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/futura_new_book_reg-webfont.svg#FuturaNewBook') format('svg'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
.content { width: 100%; font-family: 'FuturaNewBook'; font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.2em; text-align: left; /*http://www.linedmk.com/page32.html*/ clear: both; }
```

И файлы шрифтов в папку /fonts/, и тогда на клиенте всегда будет тот шрифт, что Вы уставновили.